# Vue animation is instant (no duration)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, animation

I created Vue animation exactly according to [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#Transitioning-Single-Elements-Components):

1. `transition` component has `name="fade"` attribute
2. `v-if` is in child of `transition`
3. Styles was copied from documentation

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: `
<transition name="fade">
  <div 
    class="NotificationBar" 
    v-if="show" 
    :class="{
      NotificationBar__Success: currentNotificationType === notificationBarTypes.success
    }" 
    @click="show = !show"
  >
    <div class="NotificationBar-Centerer">
      <svg class="NotificationBar-Icon-SvgCanvas" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
        <path class="NotificationBar-Icon-SvgPath" v-if="currentNotificationType === notificationBarTypes.success" d="M12 2C6.5 2 2 6.5 2 12S6.5 22 12 22 22 17.5 22 12 17.5 2 12 2M10 17L5 12L6.41 10.59L10 14.17L17.59 6.58L19 8L10 17Z"></path>
      </svg>
      <div class="NotificationBar-Text">{{ message }}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</transition>
  `,
  data: {
    show: true,
    currentNotificationType: 'success',
    message: 'OK',
    notificationBarTypes: {
      success: 'success'
    }
  }
})
```

In styles, I set 10s for experiment:

```css
.fade-enter-active, .fade-leave-active {
    transition: opacity 10s;
}
.fade-enter, .fade-leave-to {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Somewhy the animation is instant (duration is 0s).

Please check JSFiddle for [working example](https://jsfiddle.net/thvqr3km/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You incorrectly nested the selectors inside `.NotificationBar` (in SCSS). Make sure your selectors are not nested so the style applies correctly.

```scss
// Do not nest these inside another selector, or make sure
// whatever selector you use here will apply to your element

.fade-enter-active, .fade-leave-active {
  transition: opacity 10s;
}
.fade-enter, .fade-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: You are right! Thank you for the answer! Accept and up-vote.